How to keep improving this site
We have had a steady increase in the number of visits to our site over the past few months and I want to highlight some of the ways that we can continue to improve and maintain a healthy site.
Voting
It's important that we regularly and often vote for questions and answers. If you feel a question is good enough to keep on the site then vote it up. If you feel a question is worthy of an answer then vote it up.
Editing
Everyone has the opportunity to edit a question or an answer. We like to encourage everyone to add pinyin and English where it is helpful. If you notice another persons post that is lacking information that would help others to learn then please go ahead and add this information.
Ask questions
This is particularly tough, but as we are still in Beta if you have any questions that you already know the answer to but feel is valuable to have on this site then please help populate the site with good quality questions. It's OK to Ask and Answer your own questions. 
Maintaining the quality
This is about being helpful to new people on the site and also ensuring we are providing quality questions and answers. You can help by editing, commenting or in cases where there are issues flagging for moderator attention. We have a mix of background-speakers, advanced speakers and new learners. This mix means we have some challenges with quality, everyone can jump in to help.
Our site looks like it is beginning to gather momentum and we are doing a good job with providing answers to questions. Our main focus should be on voting to increase the number of proficient users and finding ways to promote the site.
